# Set html into <div> then add listener with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I did similar things with this before:

```
$.append(html,listener);
```

This will work for me because the listener will be added AFTER html is loaded.

And I can't do this:

```
$.html(html);

listener();
```

Because this way I can't ensure html is loaded.

How to do it the right way?

Comment: can you insert the elements, then attach it manually?              eg. $('#foo').html(html); $('#someElementInTheHtml').click(function...

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$('#anElement').append(theHTML).find('#newElement').listener(function(){ 
    // Some code 
});
```

listener being the event (ie: click, hover, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I'm guessing you want [the 'ready' event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready). It fires when the DOM is ready to be used. You use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { … do whatever … });
```

Or this:

```
$(function() { … do whatever … });
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what your requirements are but you might be asking about a .live event.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live